# Unshorten URL in Google Sheets

Tags: function, google-apps-script, url, expand

I want to unshorten a URL using a custom Function via Google App Script. I tried with this code but it didn't work.

```
function ExpandURL(url){
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,{followRedirects: false});
  var longurl = decodeURIComponent(response.getHeaders()['Location'])
return longurl;
}
```

For example, I want to reveal the original of this link `t.ly/1lzC` - which is `www.google.com` - using a function in Google Sheets. Please help me out. Thank you so much!

Comment: By guessing your issue and situation, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your script, I thought that your script works. But, from `I tried with this code but it didn't work.` in your question, there is one thing that I'm worried about. I think that your script returns `https://www.google.com` when `https://t.ly/1lzC` is used as `url`. But, when `t.ly/1lzC` is used as `url`, `https://www.google.com` cannot be obtained. Please be careful about this.

If you want to use your script as the custom function like `=ExpandURL(A1)` that `A1` is `t.ly/1lzC`, please modify it to `=ExpandURL("https://"&A1)`. By this, `https://www.google.com` is returned.

Or, when you want to modify your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function ExpandURL(url) {
  url = url.indexOf("https://") == 0 ? url : "https://" + url;  // Added
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { followRedirects: false });
  var longurl = decodeURIComponent(response.getHeaders()['Location']);
  return longurl;
}
```

#### Reference:

- [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: Hi @tanaike, thank you so much for the response. However, when I try to run the code on App Script, it threw exception like this https://i.imgur.com/UwHaVFy.png

The same happen to my code above, that's why I said it didn't work. Please help me out. Thank you!

Comment: @antonietta171 you're using the function in the Spreadsheet cell right ? with the URL value as the parameter?

Comment: @Karan Yes that's what I'm trying to do. I hope when it runs, I can use `=ExpandURL` as a function in GSheets. After that, `=ExpandURL(A1)` will reveal the original URL.

Comment: @antonietta171 The error you are seeing is maybe because you are running that function from the editor. If you want to test then create another function and then call ExpandURL('https://....') from that function with a valid URL.

Comment: @Karan Yes you're right. I try it on the sheets and it works. Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: @antonietta171 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: The script does not work for ow.ly links. I get a "Exception: Address unavailable" error. Is there any workaround? Have I to write a specific question? Thanks.

Comment: @tic I would like to support you. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Tanaike: Here is my question explained: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72326845/unshorten-ow-ly-url-in-google-apps-script